# Pgr_WithPoints : POIs in different tables

Tags: pgrouting

Is it possible to calculate the minimal distance between 2 points outside of routing network using `pgr_withPoints`, knowing that these points are from different tables?

I tried to group them in one table and it did work, but for efficiency I need to keep them separated in two tables

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to write a query that combines data from two tables in the way pgRouting functions requires it, then nothing holds you back from storing the data in separate tables.

You can also create a `VIEW` from the query, and if you experience performance issues using a `MATERIALIED VIEW` instead can help.